# Calling execute() on an AsyncTask doesn't call doInBackground()

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have this code in the main Activity, where `fetchxml` is an AsyncTask:

```
String GroupID = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this).getString("GroupID","");
fetchxml.execute(GroupID);
```

and in the `doInBackground(String...  paras)`, it is:

```
protected String doInBackground(String...  paras) {
    Log.d("URL+ paras[0]", paras[0]);
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL+ paras[0]);
    return xml;
}
```

Why I didn't get any value in `paras[0]`?

Comment: Does "null" show up in the log or simply a blank line?

Comment: nothing,even the TAG is  not shown

Comment: but when i change it to Log.d("URL+ paras[0]", "hi"); , it showed correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the value is null or it's empty String then Log.d won't show the tag either. Make sure that sharedPreferences returns a value. It seems that the key 'GroupID' doesn't exist and sharedPreferences returns default value which is an empty String ""

Answer (score 1):

Confirm that you define your class extending `AsyncTask` as:

```
private class Fetchxml extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{ ...
```

The important part here is to ensure that the first parameter above is type `String` to be consistent with the value expected in `doInBackground`.

Also confirm that the `String GroupID` is not null.